# Xamarin.IOS: Cannot Resolve Reference (System.Threading.Tasks.Extension.dll)

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, xamarin

When i try to run the Xamarin IOS application from Windows to Mac machine. I get the following error.

- **Can not resolve reference: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll**

System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll file does not exist under current directory in Mac machine.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is the mess that I go through every now and then and it's very annoying but I guess the following steps will solve it for you:

- Check whether or not you are actually using `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll`, You can do that by checking your project references.
- If you are using this(probably as a dependency of some NuGet package), I would suggest you go to the path in your question and check if the `dll` is present.
- If it is, then just reference it by going to your **Project>Reference>Add Reference** and go to the path and add it.
- If the `dll` is not available at that location I would suggest you check the version of the current `dll` and just remove and install it from NuGet.
- In case the `dll` reference is unused in your project, then just unload the project, Edit the csproj file and remove all References for `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`

In case this doesn't work feel free to revert.

Comment: I tried all these method but nothing in progress. The dll file does not exist in the path and my project need this file to compile and build the project. I installed the Package from the Nuget Manager but it does not work. Is there any other suggestion  you might have to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try deleting the package and removing all references from the project file?

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. There is version mismatch of IOS in my machine and Mac OS.

Comment: Can you tell me what you did so i can update it in my answer? So it helps someone else atleast

Comment: I disconnect my machine from the remote mac and plug in the internet cable to my router. When i try to connect again to remote mac machine via router, the pop up window show us and it states that the IOS version did not match. Please update the iOS version to run without any compatibility issues.

Comment: @SameedTariq Confirmed. Disconnecting from the Mac in Visual Studio, then getting the latest updates in Xamarin Studio on the Mac (Xamarin Studio Community => Check for Updates...) stopped this error, though I then got a new one informing me that I need to update XCode to 10.1, but that's possibly unrelated.

Comment: @nbrosz I will recommend you to update the XCode. It is written in the documentation that you need specific version of XCode with latest visual studio version. Just update it. You can also verify by going through the microsoft documentation.